# Is this Kindle Store App Legit or Bootleg?

Tags: youtube, amazon-kindle

This question is inspired by the answer I received to this question: [What is This Strange Symbol When I Try to Play Youtube on Kindle?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/227031/what-is-this-strange-symbol-when-i-try-to-play-youtube-on-kindle/227060#227060)

User @Banal Vulgarian reports that he has the same problem as I do in Silk Browser, but a specialized Youtube app works. I downloaded a specialized Youtube app and experienced the same success.

But I am suspicious of this app. Is this a legit app published by Google/Youtube,or is it sort of a "bootleg" app developed outside of Google's supervision which may be risky to my device?

Here is the app info:

Here you see the app in the Kindle store search results, with a non-standard Youtube logo (minus!), it has the best reviews of all results (plus!), and the most reviews of all results (plus!). Inexplicably it is the third result rather than the first result (minus!)

[image: screenshot of Kindle store search results for "Youtube app"]

I'm looking at the one right in the middle with a blue logo (unusual for Youtube) but it says the publisher is Youtube.com

So I would assume that Kindle Store would sort of vet the names of publishers to make sure they are not impersonating a major company, right? But now look when I click on the contact info for the developer of this somewhat questionable app:

[image: Screenshot of Developer contact info the the purported Youtube app. It's an email address that ends in amazon.com]

That email address looks a bit sketchy to me. Like a Youtube impersonator, to be honest.

Is this app officially sanctioned by Youtube? If not, what are the risks to me by having it on my Kindle?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the only "official" Google apps are on Fire TV:

https://blog.google/products/chromecast/prime-video-chromecast-android-tv-youtube-fire-tv/

https://techcrunch.com/2020/07/09/youtube-kids-app-is-now-available-on-amazon-fire-tv/

And only consist of YouTube and YouTube for Kids.

I believe these are the apps referenced above:
https://www.amazon.com/s?rh=n%3A2350149011%2Cp_4%3AGoogle+LLC

Everything else is a third-party wrapper/interface.

As for the blue YouTube app, [here is a 5 year old reference in a different forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/Design/comments/32fjp7/why_is_amazon_officially_using_a_blue_youtube/). It may be that as long as the app is just a web browser wrapping the YouTube site (and showing ads), Google/YouTube will look the other way.

Comment: Aha, you put me on the right track. I follow your link for "I think these are the apps referenced above" and THOSE are indeed real bona fide Youtube apps. But they don't appear on my device's app store! When I view the app info page on a web browser, there is a little box that indicates the app is not compatible with my device, so the Kindle store must automatically filter for compatibility. That solves the mystery of why there is no legit Youtube app available to me.

Comment: I have to say I'm a big flabbergasted that both Google and Amazon look the other way when some dev guy in his mom's basement calls himself "youtube.com" publishing wrapper apps.

Comment: +1, but I have very low rep so you may not benefit much. I'm going to go ahead and wait the customary 24 hours on acceptance.

Comment: I would agree with the discussion that I linked to, the blue YouTube app was made by Amazon and only wraps the YouTube site including ads, so that Amazon can put it in their marketing and say YouTube is available.